# How do I use the angular date filter with Kendo template?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

How do I use the angular date filter with Kendo template?

Here is a sample code that does not work (Kendo Release 2014.2.716).
http://dojo.telerik.com/@Xavier/OVIfE

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? See your updated sample: **http://dojo.telerik.com/@D_Learning/uBoN**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer from Kendo Support. Use dataItem.

```
{ field: 'birthDate', title: 'Birth Day', type: 'date', template:"{{ dataItem.birthDate | date:'shortDate' }}" }
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/UYOH